# What are the differences between options for base environment in CentOS install?

Tags: centos, file-server

During CentOS install, there is a choise of "base environment".

I want to install a general file, DNS, mail, etc. server, but there appears to be 3 different options for servers:

- Infrastructure Server
- File and Print Server
- Server with GUI

What are the differences between these options, and is this documented somewhere?

Alternatively, is the "Server with GUI" choise a kind of all-inclusive choise, that I can can use to be sure that I am not missing anything at a later point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the environment choice for a CentOS 7 install:

[image]

The difference is in the packages being installed, and in the out-of-the-box configuration (firewall, services started at boot, etc.) So for instance, "File and Print Server" will install Samba and NFS, "Basic Web Server" will install and configure a basic `httpd` service, and so on.

Note that this choice is done for your convenience; you can *always* install additional packages to have the server do whatever you want. So you can safely go with "Minimal Install" and then add what you need.

"Server with GUI" only means that the server will boot up on a graphical X environment. I guess it's "Minimal Install" plus GUI.

Comment: Thanks; though it did not detail the differences between the different options, but with the comment "... you can always install additional packages ..." it will sure do anyway.